# TS - cannot use object "as const" together with values every() - "This expression is not callable."

Tags: typescript

I have object with hardcoded array values. This object is `as const` because in other part of code I need TS to by aware of all possible values.

Problem is that I cannot use `.every()` method on given array from that object. TS is complying about `This expression is not callable.` even that code works just fine.

I noticed three things while trying to debug this:

1. Opposite method `some` has no problems.
2. If I remove `as const` from object, there is no errors with `every` but like I said I cannot remove this because TS needs to be aware of all values, not treat them as any `number`
3. If I use hardcoded key instead variable on that object, it works (but I need to use this as a function).

Why this does not work? What I'm doing wrong?

```
const demo = {
  a: [44, 23, 77],
  b: [22, 45, 55],
} as const

const everyfunction = (key: keyof typeof demo) => demo[key]
  .every((value) => value > 40) // This expression is not callable.

const somefunction = (key: keyof typeof demo) => demo[key]
  .some((value) => value > 40) // works

const everyfunction2 = () => demo['a']
  .every((value) => value > 40) // works


console.log(somefunction('a'))
console.log(everyfunction('a'))
```

[Live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwLYhgXhgbwFAxgQwC4YBtAFjIBoYAmAZmoHZGBdS3GAI2JJpurIBWaoMFtsAXwIQYoSFGzY50GBBBIEAMwCuYYFACW4dDAAUAawQBPYpashNMKFYAOCB-GQgAlOgB8nigkdiwcAHRqGqamAG74ADbaCL5oAXGJCDABZAAM3orKsAgxCABOVjp6huA0JqYpAYhBAOT4zaF4YcVlVtHpSQ0w-ZnZeYpK4Crd5ZX6RmB1drbWHs5uHk0%20-oEgwdYdMF0l5X0JA9vDWTC5vgD0tzAAKgAWBjIIAB4upQgQEPMwN4wMAgWDABLxfCceIIMIFSYgGFheIgADmpkiWl0c3AplazW8%20WUiNhKPR0wq2OqYDxbUJQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extended error message provides some more clues:

`Each member of the union type '...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.`

So why are we getting this error, and why doesn't `some` produce the same result? We need to look in the [declaration file](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.es5.d.ts) for `Array` to see what the function signatures for these methods actually are:

```
every<S extends T>(
  predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any
): this is S[];

every(
  predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any
): boolean;

some(
  predicate: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any
): boolean;
```

As you can see, `every` has an overloaded version whereas `some` does not. The overloaded version of `every` acts as a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), meaning that the array `T` passed in is asserted to be of type `S`. This is useful because it allows us to do things like:

```
const arr = ["a", "a", "a"]; // string[]

if (arr.every((char): char is "a" => char === "a")) {
  const typedArr = arr; // "a"[]
}
```

The problem in your example is that the type of `demo[key]` is `[44, 23, 77] | [22, 45, 55]`. This type is triggering the overloaded version of `every`, giving us two potential function signatures for the call:

```
<S extends [44, 23, 77]>(value: [44, 23, 77], index: number, array: T[]) => value is S
<S extends [22, 45, 55]>(value: [22, 45, 55], index: number, array: T[]) => value is S
```

The result of calling `every` with these signatures cannot be known by TS at compile time - they are not compatible as they contain different numeric literals. `some` on the other hand can be called just fine, since it has no such overload, and instead creates an intersection of the two types `44 | 23 | 77 & 22 | 45 | 55` which makes the signature valid.

The simplest way to get around this is just by asserting the tuples into a wider `readonly number[]` before making the `every` call:

```
const everyfunction = (key: keyof typeof demo) => (demo[key] as readonly number[])
  .every((value) => value > 40)
```

You could perhaps wrap this in some kind of helper function to obscure the assertion using generics (bare minimum presented here):

```
const everyOnObject = <O extends Record<string, readonly number[]>>(obj: O, key: keyof O) => {
  return obj[key].every((value) => value > 40);
}

console.log(everyOnObject(demo, "a"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your object structures as interfaces first, and you should be fine.

[Updated example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAkgZzMg3gKGcuALmQEEoo4BPAHhAFcBbAI2gD4BuPZJ4sim%20szacAvjhwIA9iAzIAJhAaTi6TAF5sXIsgDaAFj0AaZACYAzMYDslgLqGuPXSZPG9AVmNu3dnGInTZNEkGCBg6EAQwYGlkDQAKAGsISmIkykkYVEoABwgM%20UVJAEpY1gKlHTSbLgA6IJC4uIA3OAAbOggStTKW9pQyvQAGIvEpGUwIJuhKMIio6RNY5DiusoUKgHI4Der8Gsnpxt6O1eRj-uQhkdGAiamoGfDI6JAlxOTU5PywHLzM9eKpXKkkqyV2yH290oRzaJyB52QA2GyAA9CjkAAVAAWwDQyAgAA9slAIGg0C9kLjkCBJJgEG1WnAmK0IDUbjJJCyaq1JABzOL1UJPeYgOJbDZFEZjIJcnn8g4PWbPaRi7aSoA)